# Advanced subsetting r data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Without using a special function, can you do the following to change the values in an R dataframe from a column that have length greater than 4:

```
df[length(df$Column1)>4,"Column1"] = "replacement value"
```

This does not seem to work, is there an alternative index style I can use, or do I need to use a function?

Thanks

Comment: All columns of a data.frame have the same length... so it's not clear what you are after. Maybe your providing an example would help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but maybe you want to try `df[nchar(df$Column1)>4,"Column1"] <- "replacement value"`.

Comment: well, if column1 has values "orange", "red", and "green", than I want to replace the values green and orange by "replacement value", because there length is greater than 4.

Comment: The nchar is a step foreward, but now it gives a "requires a character vector" error.

Comment: What's wrong with you to provide a sample data? So that we could do testing.

Comment: I don't have a sample, so I cannot give that to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function to determine the length of an entry, like a word in a dataframe, is `nchar()`, and not `length()`. The latter is typically used to determine the number of entries in a vector.

You could therefore try using:

```
 df[nchar(df$Column1) > 4, "Column1"] <- "replacement value"
```

Comment: This more or less answered my question, you can use functions in indexes. I used the str_length function from the stringr package and that worked, because nchar gave a "requires a character vector".

Comment: You probably had the entries stored as factors (check `class(df$Column1)` ). This can be changed either while reading the dataset by using the option `stringsAsFactors=F`, or you can convert the entries directly into characters once you have your loaded your dataframe, e.g., with `df[,"Column1"] <- as.character(df$Column1)`. Anyway, I'm glad that it worked.